# Error with Docker daemon for docker installation on Fiware cloud

Tags: docker, fiware

I am new with the Fiware and docker technologies so I need some help.

I am following the instructions from this link http://simple-docker-hosting-on-fiware-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0/manuals/install in order to create a docker-host machine on Fiware cloud but when I run the following command:

```
docker-machine create -d openstack --openstack-flavor-id="2" --openstack-image-name="base_ubuntu_14.04" --openstack-net-name="node-int-net-01" --openstack-floatingip-pool="public-ext-net-01" --openstack-sec-groups="docker-sg" --openstack-ssh-user "ubuntu" docker-host
```

I receive the following error:

> ```
> Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: Unable to verify the Docker daemon is listening: Maximum number of retries (10) exceeded
> ```

Although, I can see the instance of the docker-host machine on Fiware cloud, but when I run the following command:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env docker-host)"
```

the following error comes up:

> ```
> Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "147.27.60.136:2376": dial tcp 147.27.60.136:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
> Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.**
> ```

I also tried to regenerate the certificates:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs docker-host
```

but I received the following error:

```
Error getting SSH command to check if the daemon is up: ssh command error:
command : sudo docker version
err     : exit status 1
output  : Client:
 Version:       18.04.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    3d479c0
 Built: Tue Apr 10 18:21:14 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?**
```

[Image with the result for the Command: docker-machine ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iSnc.png)

What am I doing wrong?

I use docker community edition for windows 10.

The docker version is:

Client:

- Version:       18.03.0-ce
- API version:   1.37
- Go version:   go1.9.4
- Git commit:    0520e24
- Built: Wed Mar 21 23:06:28 2018
- OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
- Experimental:  false
- Orchestrator: swarm

Server:

- Version:      18.03.0-ce
- API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
- Go version:   go1.9.4
- Git commit:   0520e24
- Built:        Wed Mar 21 23:14:32 2018
- OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
- Experimental: false

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you've opened your docker port (tcp/2376) in your default security group

Let me suggest you using base_ubuntu_16.04 instead of base_ubuntu_14.04

Anyway, it won't run properly at first. There is a problem with the latests versions of docker and docker-machine. As a workaround, after running your docker-machine command, you can do this to fix the problem:

```
ssh docker-host 'sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual ; sudo modprobe aufs ; sudo service docker start'
```

However, you might find furhter problems due to MTU configuration in your docker host. To solve them, you can lower your MTU with these commands:

```
docker-machine ssh docker-host "sudo sed -i 's/--label provider=openstack/--label provider=openstack\n--mtu=1400/g' /etc/default/docker"
docker-machine ssh docker-host "sudo service docker restart"
docker-machine ssh docker-host "sudo ip link set mtu 1400 dev docker0"
```